# Element type is invalid: expected a string but got: object

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux

> "Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components)
>   or a class/function (for composite components but got: object. Check
>   the render method of AppContainer.

I am getting the error that was initially shown in a tutorial video here:

https://youtu.be/6zVGVHWklg8?t=6m1s

The file has been named correctly "/app/containers/ApplicationTabs/index.ios.js" and the file contents are exactly as shown in the tutorial.

However where the app worked in the video once ApplicationTabs was "connected" I am still getting the above error after doing so myself.

I am using a newer version of a lot of the react/react-native/redux modules though. I am not sure if the convention of using files with OS specific naming would affect the way they have to be imported?

Below is my package.json dependencies :

```
"dependencies": { 
  "react": "15.4.2", 
  "react-native": "0.40.0", 
  "react-redux": "^5.0.2", 
  "redux": "^3.6.0", 
  "redux-logger": "^2.7.4", 
  "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0" 
}
```

This is the contents of "/app/containers/ApplicationTabs/index.ios.js" :

```
import { View, TabBarIOS, TabBarItemIOS } from 'react-native'; 
import React, { Component } from 'react'; 
import { connect } from 'react-redux'; 

class ApplicationTabs extends Component { 
  render() { 
    return ( <View /> ); 
  } 
} 

function mapStateToProps(state) { 
  return { }; 
} 

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ApplicationTabs);
```

This is the contents of "/app/containers/AppContainer.js" :

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'; 
import {connect} from 'react-redux'; 
import {ActionCreators} from '../actions'; 
import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux'; 
import ApplicationTabs from './ApplicationTabs'; 

class AppContainer extends Component { 
  render() { 
    return ( <ApplicationTabs { ...this.props } /> ) 
  } 
} 

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) { 
  return bindActionCreators(ActionCreators, dispatch); 
} 

export default connect( () => { return {} }, mapDispatchToProps)(AppContainer);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check the react-redux tutorial at: http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/UsageWithReact.html Maybe this will help.

```
import {connect} from 'react-redux'; 
import {ActionCreators} from '../actions'; 
import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux'; 
import ApplicationTabs from './ApplicationTabs'; 

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) { 
  return bindActionCreators(ActionCreators, dispatch); 
} 

const AppContainer = connect( null, mapDispatchToProps)(ApplicationTabs);

export default AppContainer;
```

The container is represented by the connect function and you tell it which component it should contain.

Comment: I have tried 'null' but still no luck, it made no difference and I got the same error:
`export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(AppContainer);`

I have put the exact same code in "ApplicationTabs.js" however, in the "app/containers" directory and it worked fine. There seems to be some issues with using "/app/containers/ApplicationTabs/index.ios.js"

Comment: index.ios.js should only be used to initialize the app in the root directory. If you need different commponents you could seperate them as ApplicationTabsIOS.js or the like.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I was just following the video tutorial initially. And then saw "Platform-specific Extensions" in the React docs also so assumed this was a legit method:

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/platform-specific-code.html

I have just used a file named ApplicationTabs.js now instead and its working correctly.

Comment: Didn't see that. So ApplicationTabs.ios.js should probably work but index.ios.js is reserved.